# How to change Jenkins workspace path programmatically from java?

Tags: java, jenkins, hudson

I need to trigger the build in Jenkins by sending the workspace path programmatically using java API 
so the build will be in that particular path.

To change it manually i can do that by going to jobName=>buildName=>Workspace then changing the path 
but how can I do that by sending the path for each build programmatically in JAVA

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the workspaces in a usual way, you can totally dismiss them by changing working directory (`cd /some/path/elsewhere` or `cd ${your_path_here}`) as a parametrised build step. Then you can use [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to pass the path parameter to the job.

Make sure jenkins can operate at the desired path (permissions are correct, etc.)